# How to save customer configuration from AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I plan to provide a service using Amazon AWS, so users of my service will start an instance of my AMI, they will use it and make configuration changes along the way.

After they are done and terminated the instance, the configuration will be lost unless my software save it somewhere, but where and how? The configuration may contain some big files,  not sure if it makes sense to store it in a central location.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new AMI anytime (select instance > actions > create image). After changes are done, create and keep a new image, that would incur only storage costs for that image.

Comment: Are you saying users of my virtual appliance can create another AMI based on my AMI? Well, I donot want user to do that.

Comment: You can keep the image to yourself
(private, by default) or share it with specific AWS accounts or with whole of AWS user base.

Comment: @Rakesh thanks for the idea.  I plan to share the AMI image with the public. Allowing my users to save their configuration files is a big problem right now.

Comment: May be you can create an S3 bucket for each customer and make a provision in your software to copy the configuration to these buckets? You can create a special key for these buckets using IAM so that the user can write only to their bucket. The second solution could be, you just give access to EC2 instance on your account? When they are done, make an AMI for each customer.